# open keypad on default when calling?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, calls

I was wondering if there's a way to automatically expand the keypad when I'm calling someone? I know that it likes to  have a picture of that person there, but I don't really take pictures of anyone and store them to my contacts. I want to hide that contact picture and have the keypad open instead. I looked around the settings and there doesn't seem to be an option?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is any option for that . Probably a third party app (Dialer/Call) would.